# How to dockerize a full stack web app with Angular as front-end and Python as back-end?

Tags: python, angular, docker

How to dockerize a full-stack web app with Angular as front-end and Python as backend together in one single file? I have been dockerizing the frontend and the backend separately. How could I dockerize both together into one single file (application), if it's possible?

Frontend sample docker code

```
FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine
## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
## From 'builder' stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY /dist /usr/share/nginx/html
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Backend sample docker code

```
FROM python:3
ADD main.py /
pip install all dependencies 
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

I want to dockerize both together into one single file (application) only if it's possible.

Comment: You'd have to get Python to serve the static assets generated by the Angular build, too.

Comment: do not make them one, rule of thumb for docker "one process per contianer", for angular you need nginx because anualr are just static pages and you need the server to server these pages.for python your dockerfile seems fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the question seems broad to explain, but based on your comment I will provide some guidelines.

> I want to dockerize both together into one single file (application)
>   only if it's possible.

The container is designed to run a single process per container which is normally called **" rule of thumb, single process per container"**. it does not mean it not possible but better to go with best practices form your first day.

> Each container should have only one concern. Decoupling applications into **multiple containers** makes it easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers. For instance, a web application stack might consist of three separate containers, each with its own unique image, to manage the **web application, database, and an in-memory cache in a decoupled manner**. Limiting each container to **one process is a good rule of thumb**.

[dockerfile_best-practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Now come to your second question

> How could I dockerize both together into one single file
>   (application), if it's possible?

Better to dockerize in a separate container and create a network and service-to-service communication using [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/). consider docker-compose a single file (like you need single application) which will up your both contaienr within the same network.

for example

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: ./web-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  backend-app:
    build:
      context: ./backend-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-python
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

You can also add dependcey to maintain order,

**depends_on**

> Express dependency between services, Service dependencies cause the
>   following behaviors:
>
> docker-compose up starts services in dependency order. In the
>   following example, db and redis are started before web.

So I will suggest exploring [docker-compose](https://dev.to/matthias/getting-started-with-docker-compose-4gg9).

By doing this web-app and backend-app can call each other using container name, like frontend app call backend endpoint like `http://backend-app:3000/api/v1/login`